# Google contextual gadget working only on my account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I have created google contextual gadgets for hello world but it is not showing hello world contextual gadget **on other gmail acocunts**.

I have domain also registered with gmail .**Is it possible that contextual gadgets will work for same domain also ?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to the link and deploy your gadget it will work on all accounts of your domain :

https://code.google.com/googleapps/console

You should be domain administrator to deploy the gadget on the domain.